# How to obtain Express sessionID on .findOrCreateUser of Everyauth?

Tags: session, node.js, express, socket.io, everyauth

I try to obtain *Express sessionID* on .findOrCreateUser of Everyauth.

**Backgroud of this question:**

Basically, I try to integrate Socket.IO and Express, and reading [socket.io and Express. Tying it all together,](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/)

I could obtain *Express sessionID* from socket.IO scope which is important to my project design.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + socket.handshake.sessionID 
        + ' connected!');
});
```

So far so good...
Then, **I also need to obtain *Express sessionID* on .findOrCreateUser of Everyauth.**

Although I am a beginner of Everyauth, I managed to obtain facebook/google/twitter userID etc. after the everyauth proccess configured as below, for instance, everyauth.facebook:

```
everyauth.facebook
    .entryPath('/auth-facebook')
    .appId(conf.fb.appId)
    .appSecret(conf.fb.appSecret)
    .findOrCreateUser(function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata)
    {
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        console.log(session); //  <-- if this session object includes sessionID, everything works for me..
        console.log(fbUserMetadata);
        return usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] ||
            (usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] = addUser('facebook', fbUserMetadata));
    })
    .redirectPath('/public/authdone.html');
```

The node.js console.log is the below:

```
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]: { lastAccess: 1337885971024,
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   cookie: 
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:    { path: '/',
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      httpOnly: true,
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      _expires: Thu, 24 May 2012 22:59:30 GMT,
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      originalMaxAge: 14400000 },
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   auth: 
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:    { twitter: 
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:       { token: 'w0HH4lrzMfeqCLOwd4ncHoPndlyHHqMvyXZM5mGhx8',
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:         tokenSecret: 'Pzfooy4UVRZpwXvPMJRDFXUX1LdMN59hZwz4ZkBIOc' },
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      facebook: 
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:       { user: [Object],
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:         accessToken: 'AAACrg6U8ThcBAG4QVDvIM5Qjd2gsjc3jYnHBas7g0w5QcdUJ0cgXXYBBCnmNaz8exdiFLtgXvruoErZCCXX9yitSZB3SIoAB0cKSPguAZDZD' },
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      loggedIn: true,
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      userId: 1,
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:      google: 
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:       { user: [Object],
2012-05-24T18:59:31+00:00 app[web.1]:         accessToken: 'ya29.AHES6ZRq_AFBJNLG92rSuqApI7dmE0fSq12AifJ14nxNNwlJ6OsFo58' } } }
```

Obviously, twitter, facebook and google auth information are collected appropriately through the express session, however,

**.findOrCreateUser(function (session...**
doesn't include *Express sessionID*

How to obtain Express sessionID on .findOrCreateUser of Everyauth, appropirately?
Thanks.

---

EDIT

after this post, I try to implement

```
everyauth.facebook
    .entryPath('/auth-facebook')
    .appId(conf.fb.appId)
    .appSecret(conf.fb.appSecret)
    .findOrCreateUser(function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata)
    {
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        console.log(session);
        console.log(fbUserMetadata);
        return usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] ||
            (usersByFbId[fbUserMetadata.id] = addUser('facebook', fbUserMetadata));
    })
    .findUserById(function (req, userId, callback)
    {
        console.log("######################################");
        console.log(req.sessionID);
    })
    .redirectPath('/public/authdone.html');
```

but,  .findUserById(function (req, userId, callback) never been fired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I should've done

```
console.log(session.id);
```

but, I thought whole object contents appears when I just do console.log(session);

Comment: See the [API doc for `util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors), which `console.log` uses internally; by default, it will only show nested objects to a depth of two. If you want to show the object and *all* subobjects, their subobjects, etc., try `console.log(util.inspect(session, false, null))`.